# How many streaming multiprocessors does the GeForce MX150 have?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

How many streaming multiprocessors does the Nvidia GeForce MX150 have? Where can I find this kind of information? How many DPUs are in one streaming multiprocessor of the MX150?

Comment: literally 10 seconds with google gets me this -- https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-mx150.c2959

Comment: I would expect, that Nvidia should provide these data! I was searching the information for an hour and nothing. I know about deviceQuery,but I do not have the card/notebook yet. I just plan to buy it-so deviceQuery can not solve my problem now.

Answer (score 3):

The [CUDA Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit) includes a "[deviceQuery](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#device-query)" sample, which will give you detailed information about the specifications and supported features of any GPU.

The [MX150](https://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-MX150-Benchmark-and-Specs-of-the-GT-1030-for-Laptops.223530.0.html) has 384 CUDA cores, in 3 streaming multiprocessors.